# Duplicate wordpress feed url

Tags: nginx, amazon-cloudfront

How to create nginx rules to copy the wordpress feed url. Actually, I want two versions of the feeds, one cached and one not, to simulate AWS Cloudfront cache behaviors. Both urls should function properly. For inter-feed services, the non-cached version will be used.

I tried several of the methods recommended by chatgpt, but they didn't work for me. Please advise on the best and most feasible manner to accomplish this.

***[www.example.com/request_uri/feed/](http://www.example.com/request_uri/feed/) replicate to [www.example.com/request_uri/abc-feed/.](http://www.example.com/request_uri/abc-feed/.)***

Comment: What does the caching?

Comment: @vidarlo cloudfront cache, basically i want zero cache for new url.

Comment: What have you attempted? Any (non-)caching has to be configured in CF.

Comment: I have configured the cache behavior with zero cache. Which is actually non cached for everyone. I think what i am trying to achieve will be done at nginx level. I can set CF behavior as per my need.

Answer (score -1):

To create Nginx rules to copy the WordPress feed URL, you can follow the steps below:

Open your Nginx configuration file. This file is usually located at /etc/nginx/nginx.conf or /etc/nginx/sites-available/your-site.

Add the following code to your Nginx configuration file:

```
location /feed/ {
    proxy_pass http://your-wordpress-site.com/feed/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}

location /feed-cached/ {
    proxy_pass http://your-wordpress-site.com/feed/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_cache your_cache_zone;
    proxy_cache_key $uri$is_args$args;
    proxy_cache_valid 200 302 10m;
    proxy_cache_valid 404 1m;
}
```

Replace http://your-wordpress-site.com/feed/ with the actual URL of your WordPress feed.

Replace your_cache_zone with the name of your cache zone. If you haven't defined a cache zone, you can add it in the http block of your Nginx configuration file:

```
http {
    ...
    proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=your_cache_zone:10m inactive=60m;
    ...
}
```

Save your changes and exit the text editor.

Test your Nginx configuration for syntax errors:

```
sudo nginx -t
```

If there are no errors, restart Nginx to apply the changes:

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

Now, you should be able to access the cached version of your feed at http://your-website.com/feed-cached/ and the non-cached version at http://your-website.com/feed/.